# ASPNetCore 2.0 do not include model property in POST requests

Tags: json, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ID attribute on one of my models that is auto populated in SQL that I want to be returned in a GET request, but do not want to allow it to be set manually via a POST request.

I have tried making the setter private in the model

```
public Guid UniqueId { get; private set; }
```

I even tried completely removing the setter

```
public Guid UniqueId { get; }
```

I also tried adding the ValueGeneratedOnAdd to the entity property in my DbContext object

```
entity.Property(e => e.UniqueId)
.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
.HasColumnName("UniqueID")
.HasDefaultValueSql("(newid())");
```

None of these actually prevent me from setting the value of this field in the POST request and swagger still suggests that the request should have the attribute in the POST body.

How do I do this?!?!?

Comment: In cause of the fact, that requests are actually strings, you can't prevent the Id from being set. You could set the Id explicitly to null, though in your Post-Method.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: If you solved your issue, please let us know, otherwise too.

Comment: The only way I was able to eventually solve this was to create a different class for POST requests, and map to my existing model.

Comment: Why you didn’t set the Property in your controller?